# ruby on rails - how to keep text formatting in a text area?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

how can I do this? is there a gem for this? if, say I copy and paste formatted text from word into my rails app it doesn't keep the formatting, like line breaks bullet points etc, so I'm wondering how can i achieve this? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com) - it is an open source HTML text editor.

Comment: hey thanks! this works great, how ever after saving i see the html, show up in my view instead of the edits, how do i make the html render?

Comment: Instead of having `<%= @model.value %>` use `<%= @model.value.html_safe %>. However check first whether user input is nicely escaped, so it won;t open a gate for html injection atacks

Comment: is there a difference between this and doing <% raw model.value %>?

Comment: If you llok at raw source code it reads: `def raw(stringish)    stringish.to_s.html_safe end`, so I would go with no. :)

Answer (score 3):

You need [simple format](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/simple_format)

> Returns text transformed into HTML using simple formatting rules

Some example

```
my_text = "Here is some basic text...\n...with a line break."

simple_format(my_text)
# => "<p>Here is some basic text...\n<br />...with a line break.</p>"
```

Comment: would this work for users? if they copy and paste text into my form? because they would not use \n

Comment: `\n` it is just new line character

Comment: If I understand correctly, he doesn't want to display waht user insert in formatted way - he wants user to copy text from word document and paste it to text area together with formatting (before the form is even submitted)

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably need to use a DIV/SPAN with `contenteditable`.

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

note that you can not submit the content directly for a div, so you can listen for keyboard events `keyup keypress click` or just on form `submit`, and copy the HTML to the form element.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var myForm = document.getElementById('my-form');
        myForm.onsubmit = function(e){
            var myFormattedText = document.getElementById("my-formatted-text");         
            var htmlData = myFormattedText.innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("my-html").value = htmlData;
        }
    }
    // or with jQuery
    /**
    $(function(){
        $('form#my-form').bind('submit', function(){
            var htmlData = $("div#my-formatted-text", this).html();
            $('input#my-html', this).val(htmlData);

        });
    });
    **/
</script>


<form action="" id='my-form'>
    <input type="hidden" name='my-html' id='my-html'>
    <div contenteditable='true' id='my-formatted-text'></div>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```